# how to pass all List<String> native methods to a List<Random>?

Tags: list, flutter, class, dart, methods

I'm new in Flutter(Dart) and I came across this problem. All lists of the type String naturally have the string methods like item.length, item.contains and so on. But when you create a random List type, it gets none of that. What is the recommended way of inherit all List properties to the custom one?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't provide a list type and you can't see `String` methods.

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> names = ['Dave', 'Ana', 'Robert'];
  names.shuffle();
  
  for(var name in names) {
    print('name: $name, lenght: ${name.length}');
  }
}
```